# Grammar to Language

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Having:

$\qquad \begin{align}
    S &\to aT \\
    T &\to a \mid UTV \\
    U &\to ab \mid ba \\
    V &\to ac \mid ca
\end{align}$

What language would be generated by this?

How can I obtain an $LL(1)$ grammar using factorisation?

I've tried a number of combinations but do not get how to represent the UTV part:

Something like a|ab|ba|ac|ca|aa|a(ab|ba)^n a(ac|ca)^n

Comment: You have two separate questions here that require wildly different answers. Where does this come from? (You may find interesting material in our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions).)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $U$ captures the regular expression $ab+ba$, $V$ captures $ac+ca$. The solution to an equation of the form $W \to Y | XWZ$ is $W = X^nYZ^n$.

Comment: I had a little think and came up with:

a|ab|ba|ac|ca|aa|a(ab|ba)^n a(ac|ca)^n

can someone confirm?

Comment: You're almost there, but can you explain the first part "a|ab|ba|ac|ca|aa"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obviously with the T non-terminal because of the first set conflict, so let's work on it:

```
T -> a | UTV
```

Replace U:

```
T -> a | abTV | baTV
```

Factor:

```
T -> aP | baTV
P -> bTV | Eps
```

U has now become unreachable, so the LL(1) outcome:

```
S -> aT
T -> aP | baTV
P -> bTV | Eps
V -> ac | ca
```